# How far can daredevil hear and smell?

Tags: marvel, powers

How far can Daredevil hear and smell? In the Netflix series he heard a flashlight hit the ground 40 stories below him. How far is that when dealing with miles, or city blocks? Can he smell just as far or is his range of smell shorter?

Comment: How does Daredevil smell? Terrible.

Comment: It's a bit like asking "how far can a human see?" Well look at the sun, you can see that and it's 93 million miles away, or look at the sky at night, some of those specks of light are billions of light years away. I think what you should really be asking is how powerful his sense of smell/hearing is, and that's perfectly answered by @Richard.

Comment: Another way of looking at it in terms of hearing is you might not be able to hear someone whispering next to you, but you can hear an explosion one town over. It's not so much the distance, but the frequency. For example, the normal human being can't hear supersonic frequencies, but Daredevil can (and I would imaging it would be incredibly painful)

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, drawing on the official Marvel Bio for Daredevil. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 12):

The official [Marvel bio](http://marvel.com/characters/11/daredevil) for Daredevil offers us these snippets of info

### Smell

> Daredevil’s sense of smell is enhanced enough to distinguish
>   individuals by their natural odors, and remember and identify them no
>   matter how they attempt to mask their scent, as well as track that
>   individual scent through a crowd of people at a distance of roughly 50
>   feet

That being the case, I think we can assume that he could theoretically detect a distinctive smell at anything up to a few miles away.

### Hearing

> Daredevil’s enhanced sense of hearing enables him to detect an
>   acoustic pressure change of 1 decibel at a pressure level of 7,
>   whereas the average human can only detect a sound as low as 20
>   decibels. He can even hear people speaking through a standard
>   soundproofed wall. Daredevil is also able to hear a heartbeat from 20
>   feet away, as well as identify people by their individual beat rhythm,
>   or detect whether they are lying or not by the changes in their
>   heartbeat, though a pace maker or self control will confuse his
>   reading. Not only does Daredevil’s hearing allow him to be constantly
>   aware of his own heartbeat, blood circulation, breathing, physical
>   movements, etc, but he is also able to hear and sense the same
>   attributes in other people. One of the primary ways he does this is by
>   hearing the reverberations made by ambient sounds on objects and
>   people, giving him a sonar-like sense of where things are, and how
>   dense they are. And while he is able to block out a good amount of
>   background noise, he can also be excessively disoriented by unexpected
>   loud noises and can be confused when immersed in the wash of sound
>   from a busy crowd

That being the case, his hearing would enable him to hear a distinct sound (such as a gunshot) at 30-40 miles away. His hearing is definitely better than his sense of smell.

Comment: OMG! Just imagining what it would be like to be aware of every gun shot in 1200 square miles of Western Pennsylvania.  It'd be like trying to count every raindrop that hit your windshield while driving through a thunder storm.

Comment: @jameslarge - A few years ago I was reading an article about a British journalist who'd gone for a ride-along with the LAPD helicopter unit during a riot. It wasn't until they'd landed that they told him that the "pinging sound" he was hearing was the sound of bullets hitting the bottom of the helicopter.

Comment: I'd be sad that I wasn't in an A10's titanium bathtub during that riot

Comment: In an anechoic chamber people can begin to hear the blood rushing through their head...which sounds vaguely noise-ish. Given that (among myriad other things) as a noise floor, I wonder what the theoretical limit of "perfect hearing" is according to [Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) (the theory is more commonly applied to digital signals, but in the abstract the information capacity portion still holds.)